# Quando utilizar div+seletor no CSS

Tags: div, seletores

Sempre que estou desenvolvendo o front-end de algum site, coloco direto o nome do seletor, por exemplo `.seletor1`, `.seletor2` e por aí vai.

Recentemente precisei mexer nas classes de um plugin que eu baixei, e vi que constava: `div.seletor`

Desculpem a minha ignorância, mas tenho seis meses de front-end e nunca utilizei assim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vejo dois motivos para isso:

1. Você usa a classe `seletor` em mais de um tipo de elemento, e quer criar uma regra CSS apenas para DIVs.
2. Você precisa dar mais peso para essa regra na cascata do CSS. Por exemplo:

   ```
   .seletor1 { color: red; }
   .seletor2 { color: blue; }
   ```

   Considere uma `<div class="seletor1 seletor2>...`. Ela ficará azul (ambas as regras têm o mesmo peso, mas a segunda regra tem preferência por vir depois no código-fonte). Então, se usar

   ```
   div.seletor1 { color: red; }
   ```

   conseguirá forçar a cor vermelha nessa div.

Comment: Entendi. No seu item número 1, não seria o equivalente a colocar: `.seletor a`, `seletor div`, ou `.seletor input`? Você diz que a classe só irá ser aplicada se for dentro de uma `a`, `div` ou `input`?

Comment: Não, esses seletores são diferentes: `div.foo` é uma div que tem a classe `foo`, e `.foo div` é uma div dentro um elemento qualquer que tenha a classe `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Quando precedido de "ponto" refere-se a uma classe e quando precedido de sustenido, o famoso "#" refere-se a um id.

A classe sempre deve ser utilizada quando você quer definir propriedades para um grupo de elementos e o id para um único elemento.

Quando você define `div.classe {}` você consegue definir propriedades para esta classe exclusivamente nesta div.