# Qual regra CSS tem prioridade neste caso?

Tags: css

No código abaixo, qual vai ser a cor do parágrafo?

```
p { color:red; }
p { color:blue; }
```

red ou blue?

Comment: não consegue montar um pequeno teste para provar qual cor ficará?

Comment: Porque o -1? Não achei justo... Tem várias perguntas sobre regras CSS mas não vi nenhuma sobre repetição da mesma regra.

Comment: bom, não fui eu quem deu o downvote, mas provavelmente foi como coloquei no comentário, faltou só "um forcinha" pra testa e ver o resultado, mesmo sendo uma dúvida interessante

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O *CSS* é interpretado de cima para baixo, neste caso, o parágrafo será azul.

```css
p { color: red; }
p { color: blue; }
```

```html
<p>Teste</p>
```

caso seja utilizada a declaração `!important`, o parágrafo será vermelho.

```css
p { color: red !important; }
p { color: blue; }
```

```html
<p>Teste</p>
```

#### Referências

- [Para que serve a declaração !important”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25311)
- [Como o browser lê e interpreta o css?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274991)