# A dinâmica de carga e processamento entre o HTML e CSS é assíncrono?

Tags: css, html5, navegador-de-internet

Após o *Three-way Handshake*, isto é, o estabelecimento da conexão TCP entre o cliente e o servidor. O cliente começa a realizar o download dos arquivos.

Minhas dúvida são:

1. Se em uma página HTML que contêm arquivos CSS, os arquivos são baixados pelo *browser* de forma síncrona ou assíncrona? e
2. Após de todos os arquivos baixados como funciona o processamento entre os arquivos para a exibição final da página "estilizada"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sam esta pergunta responde apenas a pergunta 2.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como o browser lê e interpreta o css?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274991/8063)